# How to use realtime Salesforce data in Journey Builder decision split?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

Using Salesforce Data as an entry source we could select required fields to be used as attributes within the journey. These attributes would become journey data and you could use them within decision splits but we want to use more or less realtime data from Salesforce in decision splits. We could tolerate 1-2 minute delay and therefore could not use synchronized data as delay would be around 15 mins which is too much in our case.
Do you see any solutions for this case?

Comment: A custom activity could be one of the solutions.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What happens in the journey before this decision split and what data would you need for that decision?

Comment: @z uzannamj We are on the stage of journey analysis therefore it's not that specific. Generally, during the previous steps within journey we plan to update an Object in SF, then put wait activity (as short as possible). After update, Service Cloud should do an API call to update an external system and decision split should be based on the data returned by the external system to Service Cloud (it could successful or failed update).

Comment: @manjit5190 Yes you're right, we've considered that but still try to investigate whether easier approach is available.

Comment: What about creating a boolean custom field on your object that let's MC know that the API call has been returned and a status has been assigned. Then you could use that field being set to true as an additional qualifier on your journey entry criteria. It's not ideal, but I'd have to think it will be a lower lift than building/testing a custom activity to accomplish something like this.

Comment: @JasonHanshaw This is the solution we came up with. I think it's a viable one. Thank you for your suggestion!